# C# XML tags to csv

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I have dozend of XML filed in the following format (short sample):

```
<namespace name="Colors">
    <green>
        <en>Green</en>
        <de>Gruen</de>
    </green>
    <blue>
        <en>Blue</en>
        <de>Blau</de>
    </blue>
    <namespace name="Subcolors">
        <perlwhite>
            <en>Perl White</en>
            <de>Perlweis</de>
        </perlwhite>
        <racingblack>
            <en>Racing Black</en>
            <de>Rennschwarz</de>
        </racingblack>
    </namespace>
</namespace>
```

And i have to extract all the language tags and output them into a csv file in this format:

```
en;de;
Green;Gruen;
Blue;Blau;
Perl White;Perlweiß;
Racing Black;Renn Schwarz;
```

Then, I give this CSV file away for translation. After translation, there is a new language added to the CSV file, french for example:

```
en;de;fr;
Green;Gruen;Vert;
Blue;Blau;Bleu;
Perl White;Perlweiß;Perl Blanc;
Racing Black;Rennschwarz;Courses Noir;
```

Then i need to read this csv file in again, and append all  tags to all the corresponding  xml-files, like so:

```
<namespace name="Colors">
    <green>
        <en>Green</en>
        <de>Gruen</de>
        <fr>Vert</fr>
    </green>
    <blue>
        <en>Blue</en>
        <de>Blau</de>
        <fr>Bleu</fr>
    </blue>
    <namespace name="Subcolors">
        <perlwhite>
            <en>Perl White</en>
            <de>Perlweis</de>
            <fr>Perl Blanc</fr>
        </perlwhite>
        <racingblack>
            <en>Racing Black</en>
            <de>Renn Schwarz</de>
            <fr>Courses Noir</fr>
        </racingblack>
    </namespace>
</namespace>
```

And namespaces or other nodes(not listed here, like "multicolor", "colored" and many more) can be nested more then once. Not every file contains every node. And not every node is nested the same way in each xml file. Thats different from file to file. But at the end, each branch ends with couple of language tags. And these need to be read and updated.

So an xml file can look like this:

```
<namespace name="Colors">
    <green>
        <en>Green</en>
        <de>Gruen</de>
    </green>
    <blue>
        <en>Blue</en>
        <de>Blau</de>
    </blue>
        <namespace name="Subcolors">
            <perlwhite>
                <en>Perl White</en>
                <de>Perlweis</de>
            </perlwhite>
            <racingblack>
                <en>Racing Black</en>
                <de>Rennschwarz</de>
            </racingblack>
            <colored>
                <namespace name="Misc">
                    <fruits>
                        <apple>
                            <de>Apfel</de>
                            <en>Apple</en>
                        </apple>
                        <orange>
                            <de>Orange</de>
                            <en>Orange</en>
                        </orange>
                    </fruits>
                    <vegetables>
                        <cucumber>
                            <en>Cucumber</en>
                            <de>Gurke</de>
                        </cucumber>
                    </vegetables>
                    <namespace name="Other">
                        <othertag>
                            <entry>
                                <en>Entry</en>
                                <de>Eintrag</de>
                            </entry>
                        </othertag>
                    </namespace>
                </namespace>
            </colored>
        </namespace>
    </namespace>
```

So not every xml file is the same, and there are different nodes with different tag names differenty nested. But every branch ends with language tags.

Can somebody help me to do this in a simple way with C#?. Maybe two simple functions like Import(readCsvPath, appendXmlPath) and Export(readXmLPath, writeCsvPath).

Comment: Comment for the moderators benefit, this feels like a homework question to me

Comment: @Horst have you made any attempts at this? If so, can you please include it so that we may see what might be going wrong? What part of this do you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

The code basically work with issues.  The original xml has perlwhite, but the new csv has Perl-White.  How do you know  where to put the dash.  I converted the small p to upper P but do not know where to put the dash.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication103
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_XML = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_CSV = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        const string INPUT_CSV = @"c:\temp\test2.csv";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(INPUT_XML);

            var colorsWithDuplicates = doc.Descendants("namespace")
                .SelectMany(ns => ns.Elements()
                .SelectMany(color => color.Elements().Select(y => new {color = color.Name.LocalName,  language = y.Name.LocalName, value = (string)y}))
                ).ToList();

            var colors = colorsWithDuplicates.GroupBy(x => new object[] { x.color, x.language }).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

            var sortedAndGrouped = colors.OrderBy(x => x.language).ThenBy(x => x.color).GroupBy(x => x.color).ToList();

            List<string> countries = sortedAndGrouped.FirstOrDefault().Select(x => x.language).ToList();

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(OUTPUT_CSV, false, Encoding.Unicode);
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",",countries));

            foreach (var color in sortedAndGrouped)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(";",color.Select(x => x.value)));
            }
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(INPUT_CSV);

            List<string> newCountries = reader.ReadLine().Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            string line = "";
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                List<string> splitLine = line.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
                dict.Add(splitLine[0], splitLine);
            }

            //now replace colors
            foreach (XElement xNs in doc.Descendants("namespace"))
            {
                string name = (string)xNs.Attribute("name");
                if((name == "Colors") || (name == "Subcolors"))
                {
                    foreach (XElement xColor in xNs.Elements())
                    {
                        if (xColor.Name.LocalName != "namespace")
                        {

                            string checkColor = xColor.Name.LocalName;
                            checkColor = (string)xColor.Element("en");  // use english name
                            if (checkColor != null)
                            {
                                List<string> inputColors = dict[checkColor];
                                for (int index = 0; index < inputColors.Count; index++)
                                {
                                    XElement country = xColor.Element(newCountries[index]);
                                    if (country == null)
                                    {
                                        xColor.Add(new XElement(newCountries[index], inputColors[index]));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (XElement group in xNs.Elements())
                    {
                        foreach(XElement xColor in group.Elements())
                        {

                            string checkColor = xColor.Name.LocalName;
                            checkColor = char.ToUpper(checkColor[0]) + checkColor.Substring(1);
                            if (checkColor != null)
                            {
                                List<string> inputColors = dict[checkColor];
                                for (int index = 0; index < inputColors.Count; index++)
                                {
                                    XElement country = xColor.Element(newCountries[index]);
                                    if (country == null)
                                    {
                                        xColor.Add(new XElement(newCountries[index], inputColors[index]));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo. The entries in both files (en and de) are identical. And in the file sent back from the translation office, there is one language added. And this language do i need to add to the xml file.

Comment: The code should add all new languages to xml.  I just didn't save the doc at end of code.  The code will only change colors in original xml file.  Not add any new colors or subcolors.

Comment: Unfortunatey this code does not work with "deeper" nested tags. Tags can be nested differently. (I have edited the first post to make it more clear.) So thats the hard part to me, as it can't be hardcoded because of different xml tag "deepness".

Comment: Can you make xml more consistent?  For namespace Colors and SubColors the colors are children.   For all the other namespaces the colors are grandchildren. I can handle by handling Colors and SubColors different from other namespaces, but it would be nice if the xml was more consistent.

Comment: Where are your colors Apple, Orange, Cucumber, and entry?

Comment: Unfortunately, i cant change the way these xml files are structured, they don't come from me. These files have all different tag names and different deep nested tags. The only thing they have in common is the language tags. I was thinking to just go through all languages tags of one branch in the xml file and check, if they match with a particular row in the csv file, if yes, then add the new language tag there in the xml file. Then, get the next branch, then the next and so on... .But i dont know how to do this in code, as i am not a software developer.

Comment: Will they always have the "en" language tag?  The code is working they way it is, but you are still missing the colors Apple, Orange, and Cucumber.

Comment: Yes, they will always have the en tag. But i need all translations to be updated.

Comment: I updated the code do to this. but your CSV input does not have all the tags like Apple, Orange, and Cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

For importing an XML to CSV file you can use folloiwng code, which is not long and easy:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
// xmlContent contains your XML file
xml.LoadXml(xmlContent);
// get collections of nodes representing translations in particular languages
var enNodes = xml.GetElementsByTagName("en");
var deNodes = xml.GetElementsByTagName("de");

string[] lines = new string[enNodes.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < enNodes.Count; i++)
    lines[i] = $"{enNodes[i].InnerText},{deNodes[i].InnerText}";
File.WriteAllLines(@"path to text file", lines);
```

The other way, CSV to XML require much more coding as you will have to detect every node to translate and add another node representing new language. This requires much more coding and is too broad for an answer - you have to write some code yourself first, then come back with more precise question about problem you would have.

Good luck.